# Primefaces : How to give alignment to a dashboard?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to show my dashboard (`p:dashboard`) as center aligned (vertically and horizontally) inside a layout unit (`p:layoutUnit`). I tried giving `[position="center"]` , but it didn't work. I am using google chrome as the browser.

How should I achieve the same ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try giving position somewhere other than div tag.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your dashboard in a section that will be center-aligned:

```
<div align="center">
    <p:dashboard >
    ...
    </p:dashboard>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are fixed, you can use a div to centralize, with the dashboard element width:

```
<p:outputPanel style="text-align: center;">
    <p:outputPanel style="width:600px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
        <p:dashboard>
        ...
        </p:dashboard>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```